# ROS package cv_bridge and libopencv4tegra can not install at the same time on Tegra TK1

Tags: opencv, ros, tegra

I'm going to use `libopencv4tegra` with **ROS** on **Tegra TK1** and I do this following this:

http://wiki.ros.org/NvidiaJetsonTK1 .

But when I install `cv_bridge`, it removes `libopencv4tegra` and `libopencv4tegra-dev` and when I install `libopencv4tegra` it removes `cv_bridge`.How can I solve this?

**install libopencv4tegra:**
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to **compile the packages from source.**

To do so, depending on your ros version, **you need a catkin workspace**.
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces

To **create a catkin workspace** use this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

Having the workspace, you need to **add sources** (and its dependencies) as a package. To add the sources 'nicely' use the beginning of this tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying
you don't need to create an additional workspace (for overlaying) but point 2.2, downloading the package, is what you need.

After adding the packages, **don't for get to build your workspace** (catkin_make).

A different approach, which is **not recommended!, is to "force" the installation** by downloading the .deb file and use dpkg to manually install. This **can break parts of your OS!**